# jQuery - Wait for a function to return value

Tags: jquery, function, return, wait

I have a jquery function for sending email with ajax request;

```
function sendMail(from,to,subject,message){
    var datastr="from="+from+"&to="+to+"&subject="+subject+"&message="+message;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: datastr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            return true;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR,status,error){
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

now I want to tell the user if the mail was successfully sent or not like this:

```
$("#feedback").html("Sending email...");
if(sendMail("from@email.com","to@email.com","MySubject","MyMessage"))
   $("#feedback").html("Email sent.");
else
   $("#feedback").html("Error sending email.");
```

but of course jQuery processes the if condition before the mail was sent, so the condition is false :-(
How do I tell jQuery to wait until sendMail has completed and returns something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the given answers are valid, I would consider keeping the `sendmail` function and the DOM modifications separate (i.e. keeping `$("#feedback").html...` out of the `success/error` callbacks ). You can do this by returning the result of the `ajax` call:

```
function sendMail(from,to,subject,message){
    var datastr="from="+from+"&to="+to+"&subject="+subject+"&message="+message;
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: datastr,
        cache: false
    });
}
```

The return value [implements the Promise interface](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), so you can then do this:

```
$("#feedback").html("Sending email...");
sendMail("from@email.com","to@email.com","MySubject","MyMessage")
    .done(function(){
        $("#feedback").html("Email sent.");
    })
    .fail(function(){
        $("#feedback").html("Error sending email.");
    });
```

Note that I removed the `success` and `error` fields from the ajax call since they're not needed, but you could still use them if you need them for something else, like logging.

Comment: You got what I'm looking for but this doesn't work :-(
It throws this error "Cannot call method 'done' of undefined".
I think method done should be used only on deferred objects.

Comment: I found this solution:
`$.when(sendMail("from@email.com","to@email.com","MySubject","MyMessage"))
    .done(function(){
        $("#feedback").html("Email sent.");
    })
    .fail(function(){
        $("#feedback").html("Error sending email.");
    });`
but there is a problem: the done and fail methods check if sendMail function successes or not, not if it returns true or false, so even if it returns false it throws "email sent" :-(

Comment: Regarding your first comment, did you change the `sendMail` function too so that it returns the result from the ajax call? Regarding your second comment, if you didn't change your `sendMail` function then it will always return `undefined`, which `$.when` treats as a "successful" value. Either version should work if you changed the line `$.ajax({` to `return $.ajax({`.

Comment: Oops! My fault. Didn't see that return before $.ajax :-p
In this case your solution works just great. Thank you very much. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#feedback").html("Sending email...");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: datastr,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
       if (sendMail("from@email.com","to@email.com","MySubject","MyMessage")) {
          $("#feedback").html("Email sent.");
       } else {
          $("#feedback").html("Error sending email.");
       }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,status,error){
        $("#feedback").html("Error sending email.");
    }
});
```

don't know what sendMail is, but if that's your check to see if the e-mail was sent, so be it ?

Comment: Uhm... this should work but I would like to reuse the sendMail function.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for your `sendMail` function to return true/false based on the results of an AJAX call (unless you use synchronous requests, wich is almost always a terrible idea). This is just the way JavaScript in a browser works, and for good reasons that I won't get into here.

Instead, you have to tell `$.ajax` what to do in the even of succeeding or failing.

One way to do that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  // omitting arguments for clarity
  success: function(){
    $("#feedback").html("Email sent.");
  },
  error: function(){
    $("#feedback").html("Error sending email.");
  }
});
```